# Delphi compatibility issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-10-seattle

There seems to be a compatibility issue between Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi 2010

I've written a school project using Delphi 10 Seattle but my teacher still uses Delphi 2010. When I transferred and opened the source code in Delphi 2010 it gave errors.

I've installed 2010 on my PC to replicate the error (screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot]

> "File not found Vcl.Forms.dcu"

Any thoughts how to get this to work, the marking/moderating takes place with Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Unit scope names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Unit_Scope_Names) were added in Delphi XE2. `Vcl.Forms` does not exist in older versions of Delphi. Instead, it should just be `Forms`.

The reason is because of the introduction of the Firemonkey framework in Delphi XE2. With Firemonkey also came the necessity to differentiate `Vcl.Forms` from `Fmx.Forms`. The same applies with many other units, such as `Graphics`. Delphi 2010 did not have Firemonkey, so it did not yet enforce this prefix.

If you need code to compile in Delphi 2010 and Delphi 10 Seattle, specify only the base unit names in your `uses` clause (`Forms`, `Graphics`, etc), and make sure your Delphi 10 Seattle project has the necessary scope(s) (`Vcl`, `Winapi`  etc) setup in `Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Unit scope names`. By default, new projects should already have this. If not, you can add `Vcl` and any other prefixes you need. This will make sure the compiler can find `Vcl.Forms` even when you specify only `Forms` in code.

Comment: [Namespaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi) and [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names) are similar but different/unrelated features. Namespaces were first introduced for Delphi.NET but are no longer used, they were replaced in XE2 with Unit Scope Names.

Comment: @Remy No wonder I couldn't find any decent resources. Thanks, updating.

Comment: @Remy Out of curiosity, if you downgrade such a D10 project to D2010, will it retain these settings? Or would the `.dproj` file get re-written without them?

Comment: never tried to downgrade, but I imagine newer settings would get lost

Comment: Thank you so much! I've removed all Unit scope name and now the errors above are cleared but I get a new error when attempting to run the app - ".exe raised exception class EReadError with message Property Zoom deos not exist". The app does not run.